# What does Friedrich List's "educational protectionism" mean?

Tags: free-trade, protectionism

My question is quite straightforward: What does Friedrich List's "educational protectionism" mean? Is it about letting industries learn in the protectionist cycle and then with the new free trade cycle letting them crush their rivals with what they already learned in the previous cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have learned it means that a country should not open its industry to world trade if it is not developed enough to compete. The country needs to favor its long term benefits by protecting its industry from international competition so it can develop and then open it up, this kind of protectionism is only temporary.